# ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/

Tags: python, django, sendmail, smtpclient, smtplib

When user enter email for  password reset then error arise connection  failure which is related to server failure error .

raceback:

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in dispatch
  53.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py" in form_valid
  56.         new_user = self.register(form)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\views.py" in register
  100.             request=self.request,

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in create_inactive_user
  193.                     lambda: registration_profile.send_activation_email(

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\db\transaction.py" in **exit**
  284.                     connection.set_autocommit(True)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in set_autocommit
  409.             self.run_and_clear_commit_hooks()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in run_and_clear_commit_hooks
  624.             func()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in 
  194.                         site, request)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py" in send_activation_email
  451.         email_message.send()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  291.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
  103.             new_conn_created = self.open()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.2b1-py3.7.egg\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in open
  63.             self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py" in **init**
  251.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py" in connect
  336.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  307.                                         self.source_address)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py" in create_connection
  727.         raise err

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py" in create_connection
  716.             sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 5):

[ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/signup/ [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pplB.jpg)

#to solve this error ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/signup/

## [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

```
   #add this to line it works
   
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
   ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the port you are trying to connect is wrong or the machine's firewall refuses your request.